# Duplicate entry: AbstractHttpContent.class while

Tags: google-app-engine

I am developong an app that uses google app engine. 
Building is fine but when I'm trying to run it,
I get this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/appengine/repackaged/com/google/api/client/http/AbstractHttpContent.class
```

when trying to run the application in android studio.

here is my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "bgu.wingmanapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    //compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   // testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
    compile ('com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:1.9.18')
    compile ('com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.18')
}
```

and backend gradle:

```
// If you would like more information on the gradle-appengine-plugin please refer to the github page
// https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-plugin

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.18'
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter();
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

dependencies {
  appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.18'
  compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.18'
  compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.18'
  compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
}

appengine {
  downloadSdk = true
  appcfg {
    oauth2 = true
  }
  endpoints {
    getClientLibsOnBuild = true
    getDiscoveryDocsOnBuild = true
  }
}
```

I understand that i have a ducplicate dependency, but I can't solve it. thanks!

Comment: Did u resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you compile this project:

```
compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
```

if you run the two below complies then you will have duplicates of the project you compiled above. And you should remove them:

```
compile ('com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:1.9.18')

compile ('com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.18')
```

Also if you are using the:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])......(I am aware you have commented it out)
```

You also probably have the same External library file as in your 'app' or 'backend' modules which are being called twice due to compiling of the entire file tree.

Comment: Removing this did the job: compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) , Was struggling with this erroe since 4 hours. Thanks